# Android Up navigation, previous activity get recreated

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my application i setup Up and Back navigation.

On up navigation previous `activity` gets recreated, but on back navigation current `activity` is finished.

Is possible on up navigation to finish current `activity` but im not sure if is the best solution.

Want to know if is a normal practice that activity get recreated on up navigation and if `finish()`; workaround is also a good solution to not recreate previous `activity`.

Thanks

Comment: The question is not clear. What exactly do you want?

Comment: means when you press up button and go back to previous activity that time ?

Comment: Yes.I want that when press on up button then parent activity to not be recreated,

Comment: can you post some code ?

Comment: I know i can easy just call finish(); but i want to be shure that is a normal practice ))

Comment: yes finish() is normal if you don't want to use finish() then call onBackPressed();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in a lot of cases (not always) is call `onBackPressed()` in the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method.

Like so:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

This way the behaviour for both the back button and up navigation is identical.
This is used in commercial apps. I am not sure if this is used in many other apps but it works for us.